# ERROR: "Enable failed: failed to execute command: command terminated with exit status=1"

Tags: azure, jboss, cluster-computing, redhat

I'm trying to deploy these clustered VMs on Azure but I'm getting the following error:

"VM has reported a failure when processing extension 'jbosseap-setup-extension-0'. Error message: "Enable failed: failed to execute command: command terminated with exit status=1\n[stdout]\n\n[stderr]\nERROR! Pool Attach for JBoss EAP Failed log\n"\r\n\r\nMore information on troubleshooting is available at https://aka.ms/VMExtensionCSELinuxTroubleshoot "

I went to marketplace, selected "JBoss EAP 7 (BYOS) on RHEL 8(PAYG) Clustered VM", the validation was okay but during the process, I got the message above.

I researched anything related my whole day I couldn't find nothing really usefull.

Please, help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like to be issue from extension deployment during the VM Cluster deployment. Most of the time, the issue should get resolved when you retry the deployment.

If the issue persists even after the re-try, as this is more of an technical issue rather than a Programming issue, I would recommend you to create an technical support case to Azure technical teams. They would help you with resolving the issue.

Reference to create a Support ticket to Azure Support teams : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-portal/supportability/how-to-create-azure-support-request